# How to limit the decimals I retrieve when pulling data from a database? Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, stock, yahoo-finance

I am trying to pull stock data using yahoo_fin library in python.

I would like to retrieve all the stocks in the S&P500 that fit certain criteria. Unfortunately, when calling to yahoo_fin I get back a 64 bit number, which makes the program run extremely slow. Is there any way to limit the amount of data I am pulling, by only taking 2 decimal places?

```
from yahoo_fin import stock_info as si

spy = si.tickers_sp500()

for i in spy:
    if si.get_live_price(i) < 50.00:
        print(i)
```

This prints the tickers I'd like to look into, but extremely slowly, I believe due to the large 64bit numbers it's requesting.

Comment: I don't think this has to do with decimal places. The yahoo_fin module just seems slow to grab the data. Using `get_next_earnings_date(i)` returns at the same speed. I recommend threading to speed this up.

Comment: It looks like the package pulls from yahoo finace chart so it's loading a a butt load of data for every ticker. might be faster to use alpha-vantage

https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v8/finance/chart/TSLA

Comment: Ah okay thanks! I only assumed that because if I don't request the price, and just request the tickers or nonnumeric data, it happens instantly

Comment: Okay thanks I'll look into alpha-vantage, this might be exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in the comments, the `yahoo_fin` module is simply slow to grab the data. I wanted to expand beyond that to point out that threading may be a necessary factor whether you decide to use `yahoo-fin` or `alpha-vantage`.

Here is a crude example of a way you could implement threading. Running this took about 10-15 seconds, whereas the other method was taking many minutes.

```
from yahoo_fin import stock_info as si
import threading

global price_list
price_list = []

# this will get called many times
def print_low_ticks(chunk):
    global price_list
    for i in chunk:
        live_price = si.get_live_price(i)
        if live_price < 50.00:
            price_list.append(i)

spy = si.tickers_sp500()
threads = []

# create threads that only process 10 values
for i in range(len(spy)):
    if ((i % 10 == 0) or (i == 0)):
        x = threading.Thread(target=print_low_ticks, 
                             args=([spy[i:i+10]]),
                             daemon=False)
        threads.append(x)
        x.start()

# wait for all threads to finish
for thread in threads:
    thread.join()

# print alphabetically sorted list
print(sorted(price_list))
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you! I am going to look for into threading since this is the first I've heard of it in this context.